# jquery - PHP methods response

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have in PHP some methods which are executing in "main method", i.e.:

```
    public function main()
    {
       $this->methodOne();
       $this->methodTwo();
       // etc.

       // returns status code (can be json)
    }
```

Now I want to get "progress" in Front-End, i.e.
**Main method started...**

Starting *methodOne*...
*methodOne* completed!

Starting *methodTwo*...
*methodTwo* completed!

etc.

How can I do this? I don't need "real progress" in point/percents, etc. only status - completed or not.

Comment: Are you using PHP on a Webserver to build HTML files?

Comment: Well echoing a line of text before, and another one after your method calls, is something you should manage on your own ... This would become a more complicated issue, if you want to immediately see those status messages in your browser, in “real time” - then you start dealing with output buffering, and that can be tricky in this regard (getting the data actually send to the browser immediately) ... if that is your goal, then I suggest you do some research into that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `echo` calls at the end of your methods if they commplete.

That will log the progression of your process as it goes on the screen.

If your process is quite complex, you can also dedicate a private method to it, to which you only pass the name of the currently running method and eventually some contextual data, and that method builds and prints the information you need to have.

If what you want is synchronous logging of your PHP process's progression, then you ar ein a world of trouble. It isn't impossible, just several orders of magnitude harder to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to see result in "google chrome -> F12 -> console" you can use code like this.

example (code for debug in console):

```
class test
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->methodOne();
        $this->methodTwo();
    }

    public function methodOne() {
        echo "<script>console.log(\"test1 end\"); </script>";
    }

    public function methodTwo() {
        echo "<script>console.log(\"test2 end\"); </script>";
    }
}

new test();
```

if you want to see result on display replace this

```
echo "<script>console.log(\"test1 end\"); </script>";
```

to 
this

```
echo "test1 end";
```

Comment: I do somethink like this but I getting response from both methods in the same time but I want to "echo" it on end specified method.

Comment: Do you need it for debug (for see when you run first and second methods) ?  or you want to develop on frontend progressbar or something like it ?

Comment: If you want to see only one result - you can delete echo from "methodTwo()" . I don't undestand what is your goal .

Comment: How do you run this php script ? via ajax ? You give me very few information for answer .

Comment: I want to display it for user. I'm using standard ajax and on done() I'm displaying response.